# Programmatic access to Android's Manage apps

Tags: android

Andorid has a Manage apps button, that allows you to manage apps. For each app, you can have the option of moving to sd card or uninstall. You can individually access each app. I want to be able to provide a single button that moves all apps to SD card. Is there a way of programmatically accessing the Manage apps? Does android has any interface/API that allows one to do that.

Answer (score 4):

Actually I figured it out, its possible and very trivial. Code shown below:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS);
Uri uri = Uri.fromParts("package", "com.test.test", null);
intent.setData(uri);
startActivity(intent);
```

That's is, this will open up the correct screen. All you got to do it look at the provider package. It has all the settings needed for different screens. Thanks for your answers, although they were not helpful at all.

Answer (score 2):

> I want to be able to provide a single button that moves all apps to SD card.

Sorry, this is not possible, except perhaps via custom firmware.

Comment: where would you get the custom firmware?

Comment: @KawlymBaygh You would write it yourself. It is far from trivial.

Comment: I am looking for direction, if I were to write it myself where would I start? I was hoping there is a class that android provides which will allow me to open up the "Manage apps" screen.